# PHP using hashtag in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have made a website with this line in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.\*)/(.\*)/(.\*)$ index.php?module=$1&action=$2&value=$3 [QSA,L]
```

The problem is, when the last parameter starts with a hashtag, it doesn't get assigned to 'value', even if i encode it with php function `urlencode()`, the link looks like this (beginning omitted):

```
.../search/searchTweets/%23tweet
```

and when printing the `$_REQUEST` variable this is the result:

```
array(3) { ["module"]=> string(6) "search" ["action"]=> string(12) "searchTweets" ["value"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string following the hashtag is called *fragment identifier* and it's a client-side only part of the URL.
It's never sent to the server.

If your URL has always the same structure, you can rewrite the rule without the last group (i.e. `^(.*)/(.*)`) and use JavaScript to pull it.

If you need any help, let me know and I'll write you an example.

Comment: Yes i am aware of that, but the "value" needs to have a hashtag in the string, so i thought passing it as %23 would work but it obviously doesn't. Is there any workaround? Or do i just need to rethink my code structure?

Comment: Once it's encoded to %23, it's working well for me, just tried `.../aaa/bbb/%23ccc` and $_REQUEST is `(
    [r1] => aaa
    [r2] => bbb
    [r3] => #ccc
)`

Comment: Really? How weird, it's not working for me. I have solved it now by parsing the string without hashtag in url, and with my own function adding it afterwards manually. It's not the prettiest solution but it works for now.